# What is a natural way to extend a function from a subset of vertices to faces?

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry, entropy

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and suppose $f$ is a probability distribution on the $2^n$ subsets of $[\![n]\!] := \{1,\ldots,n\}$. What is a "natural" way to extend $f$ to a distribution $\bar{f}$ on the simplex $\Delta_n := \{x \in \mathbb R^n | x_1,\ldots x_n \ge 0, \sum_i x_i = 1\}$ satisfying the constraint that $\bar{f}(x) = f(I)$ whenever $x$ is the centroid of the face of $\Delta_n$ spanned by by a nonempty subset $I \subseteq [\![n]\!]$ of vertices ?

In other words, how to extend a function specified only at the centroids of the faces of a simplex, to the entire simplex ?

**Rquirement 1:** $\bar{f}$ should be a continuous function on $\Delta_n$. Even more regularity would be better.

## Progress

- **Barycentric subdivisions:** This simple solution provided by user Anton in the comments indeed solves the problem. You divide the simplex barycentrically into $n!$ simplexes (called cells) of the same dimension / order as $\Delta_n$. Then on each of these cells, define the $\bar{f}(x) = x^Ta$ where $a_i$ is the value of $f$ at the vertex $i$ of the cell. $\bar{f}$ is piecewise linear, and indeed continuous!

Comment: You can extend your function linearly on all $n!$  simplexes of the barycentric subdivision of your simplex --- this seems to be the most natural way. If you do not like piecewise linear functions, you can do other things.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin thanks for the feedback. I'd be happy to here the "other things" that can be done :). One thing I failed to mention is that I'd want the extension to be at least continuous (and so can't be constant on faces).

Comment: So you want a non-negative continuous function $\bar f:\Delta_n\to\mathbb{R}$, with given values $\bar f(x_I)=f(I)$ at each of the $2^n-1$ points $x_I:={1\over|I|}\sum_{i\in I}e_i$, for $\emptyset\neq I\subset [\![n]\!] $. And "a distribution $\bar f$ on  ${\Delta_n} $" also means that you  want $\int_{\Delta_n} \bar f dx=1$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct :)

Comment: @dohmatob the extension I described IS continuous and it is linear on each of $n!$ simplexes.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin: OK, my bad. I miss-read your first response (as piecewise "constant") and thought you were talking about $2^n-1$ the faces of the simplex (hence my comment). Could you kindly explain how such a construction would be realized for a triangle (as an example) ?  How should the value within each of the 6 barycentric cells be set ?

Comment: Q2: Also, it seems the "description" of such an extension is worst than exponential in the number of vertices $n$. Is it possible to have a "simpler" extension, which is not so wiggly ? For example what about one which is continuously differentiable ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ok, for the first remark above, i think i get it: withing each cell of the barycentric subdivision, the value of the would be: $x^Ta$, where $a_i$ is the value at the $i$ vertex of the cell.

Comment: How about solving the Dirichlet problem on the simplex?

Comment: Nice. For a few moments, I also thought of formulating a pde on the simplex, with prescribed conditions. But almost immediately abandoned it (because it wasn't clear to me what continuous pb precisely to formulate / solve).

Comment: @Dirck: could you kindly expand on your proposal a one or two sentences more. Thanks in advance.